# Problem with Node.js and child_process.exec arguments

Tags: node.js, pipe

On the command line, if I run

```
echo -n "foo" | openssl aes-128-cbc -k "key" -base64 -e
```

(the `-n` flag prevents `echo` from adding a newline to the end of its output), I get

```
U2FsdGVkX1+nMW5I4eZSasPKfsUuCpbFsnn56ngEdec=
```

But when I run

```
exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('echo -n "foo" | openssl aes-128-cbc -k "key" -base64 -e', callback);
```

the callback gets the output

```
U2FsdGVkX1/CARBiGos0x9ALNhFqcIaFvZ9EUvVBxuc=
```

Why is it different? Decrypt it, and you'll get the string

```
-n foo
```

So somehow, `exec` encoded `-n "foo"` into `"-n foo"` (under Node 0.4.2).

Here's the weirdest part: I don't get this problem when I run my code directly from TextMate (via jashkenas' CoffeeScript bundle). At first I thought it was a path issue, but it isn't (making `PATH` identical in the two environments had no effect). Perhaps it's because one environment is a TTY and one isn't.

Are other folks aware of this inconsistency? Is this a Node bug, or am I ignoring something? I'm guessing that my problems will go away if I use the lower-level `spawn` instead of `exec`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps your [`/bin/echo` doesn't respect `-n`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/echo.html)? `echo` is frequently a shell builtin, and that one may respect `-n`. You may wish to use `printf(1)` instead, it is more portable.

Comment: Hmm, `/bin/echo -n "foo"` seems to work as expected on the shell, so I still think the root cause is a problem with Node's `exec`. Thanks for the `printf` pointer, though—I was able to fix the problem with it.

Comment: Trevor Burnham, if you figure out the root cause of your problem, I'd really like to know why your initial code didn't work as expected. But I'm glad you found a workaround that gets the job done.

Comment: I just ran into this myself. Could it be that Node is using /bin/sh rather than /bin/bash? From echo's man page: "Most notably, the builtin echo in sh(1) does not accept the -n option." In my case I simulated `echo -n` with `echo foo | tr -d '\n'`.